# Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm a bit confused about this problem
This is how I connect to the DB:

```
<?php

if(!defined('CMS')) {
   die('ERROR 174909812632');
}

require_once("settings.php");

try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . _DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . _DB_NAME, _DB_USER, _DB_PASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception -> ';
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
    die();
}

?>
```

When I require the above file from the index in the web root everything goes fine, connection is established, I can retrieve rows, anything.
However, when I require the same file from a subdirectory I get a fatal error as if the module wasn't present

```
Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in /home/myusername/public_html/mysql_connect.php on line 10
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, I just removed the php.ini in the problematic subdirectory and it started working